# How to set the `WSL` password from Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, passwords, automation, windows-subsystem-for-linux

**Scenario**

After automatically installing a fresh installation of Windows Subsystems for Linux Ubuntu 16.04 with commands:

```
lxrun /install /y
lxrun /setdefaultuser exampleUsername /y
```

a new installation is installed with username: `exampleUsername`.
Next, if one wants to execute a command with `sudo` priviliges, e.g.
`yes | sudo apt update`, one is prompted for the password of `exampleUsername` twice.

**Question**

How can I set that user password from Windows 10 using a script has the password?

**Attempts**

1. Create a password changing powershell `.ps1` file with content:

```
wsl passwd
wsl testPassword
wsl testPassword
```

But that returns still a manual prompt for the password when it's executed:

> PS C:\twInstall> ./pw.ps1
> Changing password for exampleUser. (current)
> UNIX password:

2. Tried piping the password twice to the passwd command with `pw.ps1` content:

```
wsl testPassword testPassword | passwd
```

which returns error:

> passwd : The term 'passwd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
> function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
> name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
> try again. At C:\twInstall\pw.ps1:1 char:25
>
> - wsl testtest testtest | passwd
> - ```
>                       ~~~~~~
>   ```
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (passwd:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

**Comment feedback adaptation**

Currently, the scripts are run on a on a Windows 10 Pro N 64 bit (desktop), version 1709, build 16299.192 with `WSL Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS`.

3. Based on [the answer suggested by @harrymc](https://superuser.com/a/1463879/910769):

3.1 First set the default user to root with command:

```
lxrun /setdefaultuser root /y
```

3.2 Then create another the user (by setting it to default user) with command:

```
lxrun /setdefaultuser testuser /y
```

3.3 run a command as that user just incase anything needs to be initialised in the wsl for the creation of the user:

```
wsl echo "hello world"
```

3.4 Switch back to root user with command:

```
lxrun /setdefaultuser root /y
```

3.5 Then set the path to the passwd file (manual inspection found it at: `/etc/passwd` hence:

```
wsl set path /etc/passwd
```

3.6 Then change the password for the non-root user with command:

```
wsl echo 'testusername:newpasswd' | chpasswd
```

which returns:

> 'chpasswd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

3.7 Retrying with sudo yielded the same error:

```
wsl sudo echo 'testusername:newpasswd' | chpasswd
```

returns:

> 'chpasswd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

3.8 Since concerns were raised whether wsl Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS had the capability of chpassword, I tried it afterwards in the wsl manually which did not throw any errors with command:

```
echo 'testusername:newpasswd' | chpasswd
```

3.9 Apparently there occurs an error in the conversion from:

```
echo 'testusername:newpasswd' | chpasswd
```

to:

```
wsl echo 'testusername:newpasswd' | chpasswd
```

I am suspecting it is due to errors in how piping works when you run a wsl command from cmd or powershell.

Comment: First of all `lxrun` is history now. You should upgrade Windows 10 immediately if you want to use WSL. Password can be added only by logging in as root.

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate which version of Windows 10 you are using.  What WSL commands are and are not possible entirely depend on the version of Windows 10 you are using.  Until you provide this information you will get inaccurate (and incorrect) answers.

Comment: Your latest edit did not indicate what version of Windows 10 you are using

Comment: Thank you, the version and build have been included in the comment feedback adaptation.

Comment: @Biswapriyo, could you perhaps explain how upgrading the Windows 10 is required to use WSL? Since I am currently be able to use the legacy Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, which is an old version of the WIndows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) without the update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running WSL from the command-line does not create a login shell.
Specifically, the PATH is not set, as WSL inherits the PATH environmental variable
from the Windows parent CMD.

You need to specify exactly the path to the `passwd` file, which might be
`/usr/bin/passwd` (but I'm not using this old product).

As another remark, the command `testPassword testPassword | passwd` does not pass
two lines having `testPassword` and `testPassword`,
but I don't think that this is required.

The [chpasswd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/chpasswd)
command is better (if available in WSL):

```
echo 'userid:newpasswd' | chpasswd
```

Remember to add the full path, and this might need some `sudo` magic.

Comment: The password will be visible in command prompt window.

Answer (score 0):

These are not necessarily the minimal steps, but they are verified in the following system type: 10 Pro N 64 bit (desktop), version 1709, build 16299.192 with WSL Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, [source here](https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/a3ql25/surpress_enter_new_unix_username_for_an_automated/).

After having enabled "WSL" in the windows features and a reboot:

1. First set the default user to root with command:

```
lxrun /setdefaultuser root /y
```

2. Then create another the user (by setting it to default user) with command:

```
lxrun /setdefaultuser testusername /y
```

3. Switch back to root user with command:

```
lxrun /setdefaultuser root /y
```

4. Then change the password for the non-root user with command:

```
bash -c "echo 'testusername:mypassword' | chpasswd"
```

Appearently the same command, [as given by @harrymc](https://superuser.com/a/1463879/910769) does not work with `wsl` in front of it, but does work with `bash -c`.

5. Verification: First actually open the WSL in the command prompt window:

```
wsl su testusername
```

6. Then execute a command that requires a password of the user named: `testusername`:

```
su testusername
```

returns with the incorrect password:

> testusername@DESKTOP-SomeDesktop:/mnt/c/Users/a$ su testusername
> Password: su: Authentication failure

returns with the correct password:

> testusername@DESKTOP-SomeDesktop:/mnt/c/Users/a$ su testusername
> Password: To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo
> ". See "man sudo_root" for details.

From that output, one can conlude that the above sequence of commands indeed set the password `mypassword` for username `testusername`.